# Modify code to print A instead of BA using asm in f2

Tags: c, operating-system

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f2(){}//no code
void f1(){
    int b=3,c=7;
    c=b+c;
    f2();//f2 call
    printf("B\n");
}
int main (void) {
    int a=3;
    a=a+1;
    f1();//f1 call
    printf("A\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Write a code inside the f2 function which will change the control of the above C program. As per the above code, the control goes from main function to f1 function, f1 to f2 and thenreturn back again from f2 to f1 and f1 to main. But, you need to write some code only in function f2, which will move your control direct from f2 to main, so that output will come only “A” rather than “BA”. F1 function cannot be called more than once during the execution. You cannot modify f1 and main function. You cannot write any printf kindof
similar statement(either in C or in assembly) inside the f2 function. The output "A" shouldbe printed from the main function only

I am not able to solve and have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It seems that they want to to dissect the stack frames and alter the return address. None in the right mind does things like that, the only area of application is dirty, non-portable hacks. Also if this code is compiled with optimization enabled as it ought to be, the compiler might just inline the functions - in which case there is no solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just out of curiosity: Where do you get such assignments without learning some basics first? I understand you will need to dig a bit on your own but before such an assignment is given, some directions where to start should be given.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.I'm currently an undergrad(4th Sem)  in CS in india.This was given as an assignment by our OS Professor

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do that safely and portably just by not returning to `f1` (or `main`). Simply do what they *would* have done had you returned, then exit:

```c
void f2() {
    printf("A\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Unfortunately, that violates the "`A` must be output only by the `main` function" requirement, so you will have to have some serious internals knowledge, and perform manipulation of the stack (however risky and non-portable it is).

The basic idea is to analyse what the state *would* have been just before exit from `f1`, and put code in `f2` that sets it to that state. State may simply be register contents but *may* involve more complex things in certain situations (think unrolling of exception handlers in C++ for example, or any global effects that may be caused by the remainder of `f1`).

That way, when you exit `f2`, the return point will be in `main` rather than `f1`. This *could* be as simple as something like:

```c
void f2() {
    asm "load sp <value>"
}
```

where `<value>` is the value you need to work out. Note that `asm` code above needs to be tailored to your environment. Since you did not provide a CPU architecture (or other specific details), I used a *mythical* CPU above with a `load` instruction and an `sp` register.

---

By way of further illustration, let's say your compiled code for `f2` looks like this (x86-64, with comments added by me):

```
f2:     push    rbp                     # prolog stack frame set up.
        mov     rbp, rsp

        ## Point 1

        mov     rsp, rbp                # epilog.
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

and `f1` looks like:

```
b_str:  .string "B\n"
f1:     push    rbp                     # prolog stack frame set up.
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16                 # allocate space for locals.

        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3    # store values for b and c.
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 7

        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]  # add b to c.
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax

        mov     eax, 0                  # make call to f2().
        call    f2

        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:b_str  # output B.
        call    printf

        ## Point 2

        mov     rsp, rbp                # epilog.
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

What you would need to do is put something at point 1 so that it will return *as if it were at point 2*. In this code, that can be effected by adding a value to `rbp`, exactly enough to back out:

- the return value pushed by `call f2`; and
- the `push rbp` at the start of `f2`.

For example, if the `call` pushed a 32-bit return address and the `push` was for a 64-bit register, you would need to add twelve to `rbp` (64 bits = 8 bytes<sup>(a)</sup> and 32 bits = 4 bytes, giving 12).

I haven't done a deep analysis to confirm that's the right value to add but it gives you the basic idea.

In any case, it's likely to need tailoring to your situation anyway, as it depends on things like compiler, calling convention, CPU selection, optimisation level, and possibly many other things.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Using the "byte is eight bits" definition, though I normally prefer "octet" for that.